# Windows surface pro file-transfer extremely low

Tags: windows-8, ssd, file-transfer, microsoft-surface-pro

I've had my surface for a couple of days and I noticed the transfer speeds are extremely low. I'm just copying some files on the ssd. The transfer starts at about 50mb but quickly plummets to 100kb/s and stays there. I have the same behaviour on my sdxc card.

Same performance on balanced and power saver battery mode.

The diskmark seems okay, but my knowledge on storage is too low to make any conclusions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't know if this matters, but, is your disk close to full?  SSDs can slow down when there are fewer available cells to write.

Comment: Windows Explorer is terribly inefficient at copying large numbers of files, regardless of their size. Pretty sure that trying to copy 3500 files would take the same time on a Surface Pro as on a really large beefy server, due to all the overhead of Windows Explorer. Try a command line copy program like `xcopy` or even Cygwin's `cp`.

Comment: I have 17.7 / 50.5 gb. That's pretty much all windows, I have only installed java since I got the surface.

My sd card is completely empty, just put it in new. 58.5gb

Comment: I have tried xCopy and it was indeed alot faster, not sure if there is a way to see the transfer speed though. So it seems the problem is related to windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I personally had a lot of struggle with transferring all the files and programs though ended up solving the problem. Surface beats the iPad in every single way. They've done an outstanding job.

PS. For anyone having the same problem I had, I followed this tutorial http://bit.ly/1VXBGZN and was able to transfer everything perfectly.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: In any case your link doesn't answer the question as it is about transferring file **to** as surface pro. The question is about copying files that are **already on the device**.